# Can I call a Javascript bookmarklet over just an image in browser window. e.g.:blah.com/blah.jpg?

Tags: javascript, image, bookmarklet

If I'm at a url... say http://i.imgur.com/JcxmE.jpg where it is just the image file, how can I make a window/div appear over the image when the bookmarklet is called?
Instapaper does this.
So far my bookmarklet loads an external javascript file, which in turn creates a div and appends it to the body.
This doesn't work when it is just an image.
Ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright it looks like firefox still renders a DOM even over images. The hello world example works only if you stick it inside a bookmarklet, but not straight in the url bar.

Here's an example that should work as long as your browser renders a DOM even on pure image urls. It will insert the image inside a container element.

```
javascript:(function(){
  var doc = document,
      image = doc.getElementsByTagName('img')[0],
      container = doc.createElement('div');

  doc.body.removeChild(image);
  container.appendChild(image);
  doc.body.appendChild(container);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it doesn't look like you can, at least not in Firefox. Even something as simple as `javascript:alert('Hello World');` doesn't work on an image. Try that code for yourself.

Comment: the alert('hello world') example works in weskit browsers, but not in firefox. However, the instapaper.com plugin works in firefox so it is possible somehow.